# Facebook login is reloading the page forever

Tags: c#, javascript, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is the script on my webpage:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '419349611446911', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                // TODO: Handle the access token
                // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                form.setAttribute("action", '@Url.Action("FacebookLogin", "Account")');

                var field = document.createElement("input");
                field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                form.appendChild(field);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>
```

And here is my `:LogOnPartial`:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Hola, <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
    <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
}
```

When I change to `auth.login` clicking the login button doesn't log in or even redirect anywhere. Just a small flash of loading and nothing else. When I use `auth.authReponseChange`, I can correctly log in using Facebook, but the page reloads over and over again.

What I'm asking is, how can I fix this bug? And why is the `auth.authResponseChange` event being fired every single time?

Example:

I log out of my local website:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

And even then, the Facebook button auto logs me in, and the loop continues. What is firing the login button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try change the event subscribe from FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange' to 
"auth.login".  This will trigger your code only the first time when user login in.

Below is taken [from fb documentations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

**auth.login**
This event is fired when your app first notices the user (in other words, gets a session when it didn't already have a valid one).

**auth.logout**
This event is fired when your app notices that there is no longer a valid user (in other words, it had a session but can no longer validate the current user).

**auth.authResponseChange**
This event is fired for any auth related change as they all affect the session: login, logout, session refresh. Sessions are refreshed over time as long as the user is active with your app.

**auth.statusChange**
Typically you will want to use the auth.authResponseChange event. But in rare cases, you want to distinguish between these three states:

- Connected
- Logged into Facebook but not connected with your
- application Not logged into Facebook at all.

Comment: For some reason, now nothing is happening. The code flow is not even entering the `auth.login` event handler.

Comment: Is this happened after changing to auth.login ?

Comment: When I change to  `auth.login` clicking the login button doesn't log in or even redirect anywhere. Just a small flash of loading and nothing else. When I use `auth.authReponseChange`, I can correctly log in using Facebook, but the page reloads over and over again.